# Best way to fetch data from Appsync in a Java Desktop application

Tags: aws-java-sdk

Asking to the "experts" here. It's not a trivial use case of AWS I think, just curious about potential avenues.

I could not find good examples, but using a regular HTTP client seems to be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I resolved this using Spring RestTemplate (as the application is Spring-based), but any other HTTP client would do.